# Python OSError no 7 (Argument list too long ) in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to open a new subprocess which will take a few input files and generate the output in other file. While this runs cleanly most of the times, when I am trying to do some stress testing this fails and gives me the following error trace:

```
File "/home/admin/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/pde-junit/org.eclipse.osgipython/util/media_info.py", line 161, in external_process

    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=shell, close_fds=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long
```

Initially I thought that the command that I was passing(it was the absolute path of 4 files) was longer than the OS could support. But even after reducing the absolute path passed to 1/4th of the original value. I still get this error. Please note that I don't get this error all the time. Mostly its after a 1000 or more runs while the path length remains the same for all cases.

Comment: what is the value of `command`?

Comment: Where's your code?  Are you sure something isn't accumulating in the `command` variable?

Comment: No the command variable is a string with an approx length of 200 chars. This certainly doesn't cross any OS limitations. I am printing this value and I am pretty sure nothing is accumulating there.

Answer (score 2):

strace is your friend.  Throw in a -s 2048 to see what's really happening.  Knowing C will help you read this, but you can still pick out long exec* strings without C knowledge.

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/debugging-with-syscall-tracers.html