# subprocess.Popen() get OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long when run the code in Linux Mint

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code:

```
temp_dir = "/tmp/working"
p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", temp_dir + "/tmp.py"])
```

but I got `OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long` when I run the code in bash of Linux Mint 18. But when I test in Fedora, macOS, FreeBSD, Ubuntu (they have many shell: fish, zsh,...) I don't receive any errors. Even I use

```
print(subprocess.check_call(["python3", temp_dir + "/tmp.py"], shell=True))
```

, the same error has been reached.

The command is really short, and I have no idea why I get that error.

I have google hundreds of result, but I can't get the solution of my problem.

Comment: Does `tmp.py` include any subprocess calls?

Comment: No. `tmp.py` is a small code, it contains `print('something')` only.

Comment: You need to increase your ulimit -s https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401797

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `shell=True`, the `check_call` expect the arguments as one command just like you run the command in terminal. Try this. Hope will work.

```
print(subprocess.check_call(["python3 "+ temp_dir + "/tmp.py"], shell=True))
```

Comment: It's still get that error. I had removed `shell=True`, but nothing had changed.

Comment: Use shell=True but remove the comma after `python3`.

Comment: Can you run the command directly from `linux mint` terminal i.e `python3 /tmp/working/tmp.py`. I suspect it wont work.

Comment: Haris Nadeem has posted that link.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try these two and see if they work

```
temp_dir = "/tmp/working"
p = subprocess.call("python3 " + temp_dir + "/tmp.py", shell=True)
```

If that doesn't work you can also try

```
import os
command = "python3 " + temp_dir + "/tmp.py"
p = os.popen(command ,"r")
```

Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Interesting, could you please post the complete error message trace. I am curious to see what is happening underneath

Comment: When I use `os.popen()`:
`File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 1035, in popen
    bufsize=buffering)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long`

Comment: It is as I had thought. This is an issue with the way the python library handles the OS environment passed along with command. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788292/intermittent-oserror-errno-7-argument-list-too-long-with-short-command-12) article as it will explain better than I can

Comment: Ok, so what can I do? I tried `subprocess.Popen("python3 " + temp_dir + "/tmp.py", shell=True, env={"PATH": "/usr/bin"})` but it's still error.

Comment: Try this:

`import subprocess, os`

`my_env = os.environ.copy()`

`my_env["PATH"] = "/usr/sbin:/sbin:" + my_env["PATH"]`

`subprocess.Popen(my_command, env=my_env)`

Comment: Also please mention which python3 version you are using because according to the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)  `bufsize now defaults to -1 to enable buffering by default to match the behavior that most code expects. In versions prior to Python 3.2.4 and 3.3.1 it incorrectly defaulted to 0 which was unbuffered and allowed short reads`

Comment: I use Python 3.5, and all my computer I tested use Python 3.6. I think `bufsize` doesn't cause the error.

Comment: I have same issue with Env param as input . Is any one found solution for it?

Comment: This issue never did seem to get resolved, sorry. The issue seems to be with the way python is interacting with Linux mint. My only suggestions would be to install something like anaconda which would change your python interpreter or possibly work on a docker container of some sorts.

Comment: You can of course re-open the question in a new question and link this one and see what feedback you get.