# How to avoid a "[Errno 7] Argument list too long" when a script has to be restarted?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script which runs without any problems for several days/weeks.
Based on some definitions, I need to restart this entire script.
The restart itself is realized with the following line. And this works in most cases without any problems.

```
os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
```

Sometimes it is not successful and I see the following error message. I cannot find any distinguisher between the moments when it works fine and when not.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "abc.py", line 301, in pinging
    os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long
```

What could I change in the code or how should I restart a script to prevent this error message?

Comment: ``sys.argv`` should accept several MB of data. When you need to pass that much (or more) around, consider to use proper data channels such as stdin, pipes or files.

Comment: Do you extend the environment (e.g. via ``os.environ``) over the runtime of the program?

Comment: No I am not extending the environment. Have to learn how to make it. Anyway wondering why it usually works and sometimes not.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33924766/18771

Comment: "Anyway wondering why it usually works and sometimes not." We cannot really do much else than guess as well. Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: sys.argv is very short as it has just 2 arguments. sys.executable should return the path. So here the questions rising: 1) is sys.argv changing over runtime? 2) could sys.executable be the culprit as I am running everything in openshift so its not able to find the path? I could print len() of sys.argv and print sys.executable the line before execv, this could maybe spot light, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is**

Everytime `os.execv` runs, a new script starts, but the actual running script is not stopped. So by this `sys.argv` is becoming longer until it gives the error.

**The solution is**

Avoid that a new script starts by handling the situation in another way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? ``execv`` replaces the old program, so it should "stop" the running script. In my tests using basically just ``print(sys.argv)`` ``os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)``, the ``sys.argv`` did not increase in size.